# How to add same data value multiple times in hash map?

Tags: java, android, for-loop, hashmap

I want to add the values in hashmap to send as form data. Now some values are single and some values I need t add  multiple times in for loop of an array list.

code :

```
  data = new HashMap<String, String>();

                data.put("save", "1");
                data.put("disc", "");
                data.put("term_condi", edt_payment_terms.getText().toString());
                data.put("memo", edt_item_memo.getText().toString());
                data.put("note", edt_note.getText().toString());
                data.put("due_date", mDueDate);
                data.put("pay_terms", edt_payment_terms.getText().toString());
                data.put("currency_id", sessionData.getString("currency_id",""));
                data.put("currency_value",sessionData.getString("currency_value",""));
                data.put("invoice_date", mInvoiceDate);
                data.put("discount", mDiscount.toString());
                data.put("shipping", mShipping.toString());
                data.put("total", mTotalamount.toString());

                for (String email : mEmailList) {
                    data.put("send_to[]", email.toString());
                }

                for(Item item : mItemArrayList) {

                    data.put("tax[]", item.getItemTax());
                    data.put("qty[]", item.getItemQuantity());
                    data.put("item_name[]", item.getItemName());
                    data.put("unit_price[]", item.getItemUnitPrice());
                    data.put("disc[]", item.getDescription());

                }

                data.put("send", "1");
```

As I run for loop, I am getting only last index of it in my hashmap. I cant initialize the hash map in a for loop, all other single values would get double.
How can I do this? Please help.Thank you..

Comment: You cannot add multiple values with same key in a `HashMap`. It seems like you should be creating a new `HashMap`'s inside the for loop

Answer (score 0):

You could:
1.Use a map that has a list as the value. Map>.
2.Create a new wrapper class and place instances of this wrapper in the map. Map.
3.Use a tuple like class (saves creating lots of wrappers). Map>.
4.Use mulitple maps side-by-side.
Examples

1. Map with list as the value

   // create our map
   Map> peopleByForename = new HashMap>();

   // populate it
   List people = new ArrayList();
   people.add(new Person("Bob Smith"));
   people.add(new Person("Bob Jones"));
   peopleByForename.put("Bob", people);

   // read from it
   List bobs = peopleByForename["Bob"];
   Person bob1 = bobs[0];
   Person bob2 = bobs[1];

The disadvantage with this approach is that the list is not bound to exactly two values.

2. Using wrapper class

   // define our wrapper
   class Wrapper {
       public Wrapper(Person person1, Person person2) {
          this.person1 = person1;
          this.person2 = person2;
       }

   ```
   public Person getPerson1 { return this.person1; }
   public Person getPerson2 { return this.person2; }

   private Person person1;
   private Person person2;
   ```

   }

   // create our map
   Map peopleByForename = new HashMap();

   // populate it
   Wrapper people = new Wrapper()
   peopleByForename.put("Bob", new Wrapper(new Person("Bob Smith"),
                                           new Person("Bob Jones"));

   // read from it
   Wrapper bobs = peopleByForename["Bob"];
   Person bob1 = bobs.Person1;
   Person bob2 = bobs.Person2;

The disadvantage to this approach is that you have to write a lot of boiler-plate code for all of these very simple container classes.

3. Using a tuple

// you'll have to write or download a Tuple class in Java, (.NET ships with one)

```
// create our map
Map<string, Tuple2<Person, Person> peopleByForename = new HashMap<string, Tuple2<Person, Person>>();

// populate it
peopleByForename.put("Bob", new Tuple2(new Person("Bob Smith",
                                       new Person("Bob Jones"));

// read from it
Tuple<Person, Person> bobs = peopleByForename["Bob"];
Person bob1 = bobs.Item1;
Person bob2 = bobs.Item2;
This is the best solution in my opinion.

4. Multiple maps

// create our maps
Map<string, Person> firstPersonByForename = new HashMap<string, Person>();
Map<string, Person> secondPersonByForename = new HashMap<string, Person>();

// populate them
firstPersonByForename.put("Bob", new Person("Bob Smith"));
secondPersonByForename.put("Bob", new Person("Bob Jones"));

// read from them
Person bob1 = firstPersonByForename["Bob"];
Person bob2 = secondPersonByForename["Bob"];
```

The disadvantage of this solution is that it's not obvious that the two maps are related, a programmatic error could see the two maps get out of sync.

Answer (score 0):

In `HashMap` if you add values with the same key the `HashMap` will replace the existing key with the last value. [In the document of HashMap](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html)

```
public V put(K key, V value)
```

**Associates the specified value with the specified key in this map. If the map previously contained a mapping for the key, the old value is replaced.**

Ex:

```
 HashMap map = new HashMap<String, String>();
 map.put("123", "1");
 map.put("123", "2");
```

In this case, the `map` size is 1 (key = "123", value = "2").

I think you should create a string with format "str1,str2,str3" and put this string into the HashMap. In the form where you receives the values you using String.split(",") to get per value.